# VBA Val Function Changing Value?

Tags: vba

An equation produces this value as Variant/Double X: 36.0418746812314

But:
X <> Val(X) is true
X <> CStr(X) is false
X <> CDdl(X) is false

How is Val() changing the value?
When viewed in the watch list applying X = Val(X) does not appear to change the value or type of X.  But somehow it is different.

For instance:
A = X - Val(X) is very small, but not zero (2.1316282072803E-14).
B = X - CStr(X) is very small, but not zero (2.1316282072803E-14).
C = X - CDbl(X) is zero.

Update:
Thanks everyone for your replies and answers.  Here is some additional background.

Formula for dividend adjusted close price.  Reportedly used by Yahoo Finance.
A1 = A0 + A0 * (((P1 / S) - P0 - D) / P0)

Split and Dividend Adjusted Close Price
Ticker Symbol: INTC
Date: Friday, August 29, 1980
0.306757021582758 (Yahoo Finance calculated)
0.306757021582704 (My VBA calculation)

Converting A1 to string CStr(A1) or applying Val(A1), then my VBA result matches the Yahoo Finance calculated value.
It's not really a material difference but nice to understand why and how to make it match for purpose of formula validation.

Formula source, components details and explanation.
"How Yahoo Calculates the Adjusted Closing Price"
http://marubozu.blogspot.com/2006/09/how-yahoo-calculates-adjusted-closing.html

Comment: Are you sure that is the exact value of `X`?  I just tested and got `False` for all tests.  (FWIW - `X <> CStr(X)` is implicitly equal to `CStr(X) <> CStr(X)` because VBA will need to perform a type conversion before performing the comparison.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider this MCVE:

```
Sub TestingVal()
  Dim x As Double, y As Double
  x = 36.0418746812314 + 2.1316282072803E-14
  y = Val(x)
  Debug.Print x, y, x <> y       ' 36.0418746812314  36.0418746812314  True
End Sub
```

Both x and Y **display** the same way, due to the **displaying precision**. But their actual values (binary representations) are different.

For info, here are the binary representations of x and y in the `IEEE-754` format:

```
0100000001000000000001010101110000100110010010010011010110101110
0100000001000000000001010101110000100110010010010011010110101011
'                                                            ^^^
```

Only the last 3 bits (of the mantissa) differ! This difference was not big enough to show when they are displayed in base 10 with 14 decimal digits.

Now consider the [Val Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264296.aspx):

> Returns the numbers contained in a string as a numeric value of appropriate type

That means, in `Val(x)`, the number `x` was first converted to a `String` to match the parameter type of the function. This resulted in its *displayed value* in Base 10. Then `Val` converted it back to a number and we stored it in `y`. Since in the first phase the displayed value was not the *exact* value, some bits of precision were lost and we got `x <> Val(x)`.

As conclusion, when precision matters to the last bit in your calculations, dont apply `Val` on a number. Even if you dont know whether your initial variant is a double or a string, use `CDbl` which works well in both cases.

Comment: It looks like a **LOT** of effort has gone into research for that answer - well done!

Comment: @YowE3K Thanks mate. More importantly I have learned a few "huge" things today. We never stop learning, even when we start loosing our hair...

Comment: I'm definitely losing braincells, but haven't yet started to lose my hair (much to my barber's disgust - keeps complaining that my hair is too thick and will need to charge me extra to sharpen the scissors :( )

Comment: And, of course, the other thing to be wary of is the attempt to use a `Double` in **any** sort of equality / inequality comparison - e.g. `49 * CDbl(1 / 49) = 1` is `False` due to the rounding of the final bit.  (If it was just `49 * (1 / 49) = 1` you would get `True` - not sure whether that is due to optimisation, or whether it stores extra bits in the intermediate calcs)

Comment: Ah... another curious result.

Comment: Why not just use `CDec` instead of `CDbl`, and retain the printed precision? `Debug.Print CDec(36.0418746812314) + CDec(2.1316282072803E-14) 'Prints  36.041874681231421316282072803
`

Comment: I suppose the take-away is that you should *only* ever use `Val` in very specific situations, where: **A.** The input is a string, and **B.** The string is in US format, and **C.** The precision of the string is expressible as a Double?

Comment: @ThunderFrame perfect, `CDec + CDec` shows the difference in decimal form. But not `CDec(x)` though, we fall back into the same problem with `Val(x)`, as if `x` was first converted to string before passed to `CDec`??? Although [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278896.aspx) says *"expression argument is any string expression or numeric expression"*, it seems that an implicit conversion of the parameter (`x`, double) to string did occur :/

Comment: @ThunderFrame I agree on the flaw of using `Val`. Good advice.

Comment: @YowE3K I think it depends on if the expression can be calculated at compile time. For example `49 * (1 / 49) = 1` is False if any of the numbers is replaced with a variable.

Comment: @Slai If it was "compile-time v run-time" then constants would give `True`, but `Const a As Double = 1 / 49: Const b As Double = a * 49: Const c As Double = 49 * (1 / 49): Debug.Print b = 1, c = 1` will give `False  True`, so I still think that intermediate expressions are being calculated with greater precision than a `Double`, or code is being optimised by rearranging expressions.

Answer (score 1):

The `CDbl` function is relative to your regional settings. The `Val` function is relative to US regional settings.

If you provide a value in your local regional settings to the `Val` function, it will be interpreted as if it is in US format (period for decimal separator, comma for thousands separator etc).

My PC is set to EN-AU settings (which are similar to EN-US settings), and `Val(36.0418746812314) = 36.0418746812314` returns `True`, or in your syntax, `Val(36.0418746812314) <> 36.0418746812314` returns `False`

Comment: Hi. Problem actually is that the actual value of x is `36.0418746812314 + 2.1316282072803E-14` but it displays as `36.0418746812314`... and `Val(x)` truncates it back to what is displayed. (even with US locale) :(. I am trying to figure out how to display `x` with more precision.

Comment: @A.S.H Use `CDec`